# Android application require double click to login

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

I have a basic login class. Which handles to read user information from database and compare it so If all credentials are correct user may login.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
    passwordText = findViewById(R.id.PasswordGetter);
    userNameText = findViewById(R.id.userNameGetter);
    infoText = findViewById(R.id.infoText);
    buttonLogIn = findViewById(R.id.buttonLogIn);
    buttonRegister = findViewById(R.id.buttonRegister);

    buttonRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent registerIntent = new Intent(LogInActivity.this, RegisterActivity.class);
            startActivity(registerIntent);
        }
    });

    buttonLogIn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(checkInternetPermission()){
                if (!emptyChecker.isEmpty(userNameText) && !emptyChecker.isEmpty(passwordText)) {
                    userName = userNameText.getText().toString();
                    password = passwordText.getText().toString();
                    boolean ifMatched = false;
                    try {
                        ifMatched = logInValidator(userName);
                    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (InvalidKeySpecException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    if(ifMatched){
                        String writeToFile = null;
                        writeToFile = getTextToWrite();
                        writeFileExternalStorage(writeToFile);
                        Intent mainIntent = new Intent(LogInActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                        startActivity(mainIntent);
                    }
                    else
                        infoText.setText(getString(R.string.UserNotFound));
                } else
                    infoText.setText(getString(R.string.EmptyField));
            }
            else
                requestInternetPermission();
        }
    });
}
```

Here is the code for onCreate method for this login activity.
Every time I press Login button it gives error. It gives error for user not found (infoText.setText(getString(R.string.UserNotFound));. This doesn't matter user is existed or not existed. Either way it says user not found. But at second click application works normally. If user credentials are correct login will be successful. If credentials are wrong doesn't change how many times you click login , you can't login.

I want to ( of course ) user may login first time to click on login button. How can I do that ?

This is the method for making validation controls.

```
    private boolean logInValidator(String userName) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException,InvalidKeySpecException{

    DatabaseReference rootRef = databaseManager.getReference();
    DatabaseReference usersRef = rootRef.child("user");
    Query queryUsernameFinder = usersRef.orderByKey().equalTo(userName);
    ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                user = ds.getValue(User.class);
            }
            String passHash = user.getPasswordHash();
            try {
                validated = passwordHandler.validatePassword(password, passHash);
            } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (InvalidKeySpecException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Log.d("error", databaseError.getMessage()); 
        }
    };
    queryUsernameFinder.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);

    return validated;
}
```

I make debug for it but I couldn't fix it.

Comment: `logInValidator` method is making a an async call Which will call  `ValueEventListener` so you can not just return it from method .. Either you use some blocking code or just do all validation inside `onDataChange`.

Comment: Could you also post your XML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are performing an async operation but return a boolen directly from the method.

Change your `loginValidator` method like this:

- add a callback parameter
- make it void
- look out for the `finally` block
- also return false in onCancelled

  ```
  private void logInValidator(String userName, SimpleCallback<Boolean> finishedCallback) {
  // Everything stays the same in the method, but change your valueListener like this:

  ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
  @Override
      public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
          for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
              user = ds.getValue(User.class);
          }
          String passHash = user.getPasswordHash();
          validated = false;
          try {
              validated = passwordHandler.validatePassword(password, passHash);
          } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
          } catch (InvalidKeySpecException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
          } finally {
              finishedCallback.run(validated); // send the result to the callback
          }
      }
      @Override
      public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
          Log.d("error", databaseError.getMessage()); 
          finishedCallback.run(false); // send false return
      }
  };
  // this method is now void!
  }
  ```

To use such callbacks I suggest you create a generic callback interface - I use a similar one in my libraries. It can return any value:

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface SimpleCallback<T> {
    void run(T data);
}
```

And now, in your loginActivity, you call this:

```
loginValidator(username, (success) -> {
    if (success) {
        String writeToFile = null;
        writeToFile = getTextToWrite();
        writeFileExternalStorage(writeToFile);
        Intent mainIntent = new Intent(LogInActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(mainIntent);
    } else
      infoText.setText(getString(R.string.UserNotFound));
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I am trying to solve this problem for days. I searched everywhere but I couldn't find this. So every time I make a async operations can I use this method to prevent double click ? Can I use this same simpleCallback interface for this async operations too ? And how this Interface works ? We don't implement it in LogInActivity but it works. We don't write a body for this abstract method but it still works. Is this Interface uses a feature from Android or premade class perhaps ? Thanks again very helpful answer I appreciate it.

Comment: Oh no, this is not black magic. Just a standard functional interface. Maybe this can help you understand, what's behind the scenes: A functional interface is nothing more than an Interface with only one single function. Another example (from Android system would be ``Runnable`` - pretty sure you already saw this).
Whats happening here is simply, that Java can "implicitly" map a parameter of such an interface type to an anonymous implementation --- that's what the ``(success) -> { }`` lambda is ... an anonymous implementation.
Glad I could help.

Comment: Thank you very much. I understand it now. Thank you again